# How can I find the area of this region?

Tags: geometry

In this diagram, how can I find the area containing point $J$ (aka the area where both circles overlap, and to the right of $\overline{CE}$ and above $\overline{AF}$, given $\overline{AG} \bot \overline{AF}$, $\overline{CH} \bot \overline{CI}$, and that points that look like centerpoints are such. The equation needs to take in any radius for both circles. The distance between $A$ and $C$ is 25 on the Y axis and 15 on the X.

[image: Diagram]

(Sorry for the sorta messy diagram. I did my best.)

Comment: what are the relation between the center of A and center of C..?

Comment: @Soke Oh whoops, I also know the distance between the two.

Comment: As is, it seems one could move point $A$ keeping $AC=25,$ slightly to its left, and this would change the area of the region containing point $J.$ The line $AF$ would then move downward, line $CE$ stay where it is, so the area of "region $J$" would increase.

Comment: @coffeemath Just fixed that. My orginial calculation was wrong, too.

Comment: Alpha-- Thanks for fixing. So you maybe can get the area using integration, given you set up constants say $c,d$ for the radii of the two circles, but it may be involved to compute that.

Comment: Alpha^3: There won't be a single formula for all cases. In your diagram, the two circles intersect at a point above and a bitt to the left of $F,$ and that would be one case (among many) to compute by integration. Even in that case one needs the coordinates of this intersection point to set it up.